# Problems with particle coloring

Tags: particles, selection-tools, color

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U) tutorial, and I'm having a problem specifically with [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNmnPXY9UQA&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=0s) [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZ5ungDgFNc&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=0s) videos. In the tutorial, when he selects the frosting of the donut after adding the sprinkles as particles, the sprinkles look like they have a selection outline around them as if they are individual objects. When I do the same thing, only some of them have the selection. Then when I try to add random color from the second video, only the ones that were selected have the color changed.

[image: selection problems]
[image: coloring problems]

Here's my .blend file: [image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KAMv9KrW